# Custom PMD rule integration with hudson

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, sonarqube, pmd

I have written a custom PMD rule specific to my project requirements that is working fine with sonar in standalone mode (following the steps given in [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extend+coding+rules) link). I need to integrate the same to hudson.

How can I integrate the custom PMD-sonar rule to Hudson, what is the best way to do so ? Do I need to make changes to the sonar-hudson plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the way out myself. It seems there is no extra configuration required for hudson as the configuration manager itself takes only the url to sonar. Standalone PMD custom rule with sonar integration is sufficient.